# get_current_site() is undefined

Tags: php, functions

I get the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_site() in XXXXXXXX`
Why is this happening? Do I need to load something before I can use that function? Is my Installation wrong?

Thanks in advance

PS: my Code (if you need it)

```
$f = function () {     
    ob_start();    
    var_dump(get_current_site());   
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/dump.html', ob_get_clean());  
return;  
// I actually want to put styles here later, which change with every page  
};  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', $f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_current_site()` is a function for getting the current [Multisite Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). As with other multisite-related functions, it is not available to use if your site is not configured as a multisite network.

<strike>I can't tell from your code what you're attempting to use the function for, so I can't offer a suggestion for what to use instead.</strike>

If you want to check if you're on a specific page you can use `is_page()` along with the slug of ID if the page you're checking for:

```
if ( is_page( 'about-us' ) ) {

}

if ( is_page( 5 ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just need the page id I'm on. I just haven't found anything else ... Seems like I'll search on